How can i find a list in a string ignoring any number of spaces and new lines in between each element?
I'm currently having an hard time solving and generalizing the following problem:
I have a table, which is stored as a nested list, and I have a text which contains the content of the table as well as other text.
I do not now how the table is convererted in string in the text exactly: sometimes there is a space separating the cells, sometimes a new line, sometime both and sometimes nothing.
My goal is to find the block of text containing the table and substituting it with a placeholder (i.e. table_1).
I was thinking of using regular expressions so I looked into it and in the end I did something like this:
table_as_string = ""
for row in table:
    for elem in row:
        table_as_string += elem + r"[\r\n\t\f\v ]*"

Before using the sub method I tried to look if the regular expression of the table I'm using as a sample is in the text as follows:
result = re.search(table_as_string, text)

This returns that it didn't find any matching but I'm sure there should be one. I also tries using \s* but nothing. Am I doing something wrong? The text in the cells can have characters like *, , \n, etc.., can this be a problem?
Any help is apreciated!

[\r\n\t\f\v ] is essentially the same as the built-in \s escape for whitespace.

*"The text in the cells can have characters like , , \n, etc.., can this be a problem?": yes. See Escape special characters in a Python string and Escaping regex string

If there can be other special characters that you want to ignore, add them to the [\r\n\t\f\v ] character set.

sometimes there is a space separating the cells, sometimes a new line, sometime both and sometimes nothing If it's nothing, how do you tell where one cell ends and the next one starts?

maybe better show example data in question (not in comments)
